# What is the difference between memset and memcpy in C

Tags: c, memcpy, memset

I've read the function headers, but I'm still not sure what exactly the difference is in terms of use cases.

Comment: The headers are not usually the best place to look for documentation.  In the case of C, the ultimate reference is the Standard, but any decent reference text (e.g. K&R, H&S) should describe the standard library functions adequately.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/ also has a very good online reference.

Comment: or opengroup.org (which curates the POSIX standard). If you use cplusplus.com, you have to ignore the stuff about C++...

Answer (score 54, accepted):

`memcpy()` copies from one place to another. `memset()` just sets all pieces of memory to the same value.

Example:

```
memset(str, '*', 50);
```

The above line sets the first 50 characters of the string str to * (or whatever second argument of the memset).

```
memcpy(str2, str1, 50);
```

The above line copies the first 50 characters of str1 to str2.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that the mem*() functions *don't* know about string terminators. The second example above will do bad things if str1 is shorter than 50 characters. It's only safe to use mem*() functions on string data when you've already validated the lengths involved.

Comment: absolutely. take this as only an example.

Comment: it might be worth pointing out that if you do want to copy two strings use:
strncpy(str2, str1, 50);
This will safely copy str1 to str2 stopping the copy at the first '\0' string terminator it detects in str1, but has the safety net that it will not copy more than 50 characters should str1 be corrupt or longer than 50 bytes.

Comment: Of course strncpy goes wrong in some cases where strcpy would work: for instance if you've arranged for str2 to be as long as necessary (i.e. length of str1, with space for nul terminator), but str2 is actually shorter than than your 50-char limit. strncpy is not a safe version of strcpy, it just has different pitfalls. In any case use (or re-implement) strcpy_s instead: it always nul-terminates the result whereas strncpy does not always nul-terminate. strcpy_s also fails instead of truncating overlong strings: truncation usually leads to another bug further down the line.

Comment: Well, this is correct but more specifically the mem*() functions don't know or care about strings at all. They deal with memory.

Answer (score 16):

`memset()` sets all of the bytes in the specified buffer to the same value, `memcpy()` copies a sequence of bytes from another place to the buffer.

```
char a[4];
memset(a, 7, sizeof(char)*4);
/*
* a is now...
*
* +-+-+-+-+
* |7|7|7|7|
* +-+-+-+-+
*/

char b[] = {1,2,3,4};
char c[4];
memcpy(c, b, sizeof(char)*4);
/*
* c is now...
*
* +-+-+-+-+
* |1|2|3|4|
* +-+-+-+-+
*/
```

Comment: Probably worth noting that `sizeof(char)` is `1` by definition, so the `sizeof(char)*`s are redundant.

Comment: @zenith sure, for the specific example, but it's all fun and games until someone assumes that ints are fixed size too.

Comment: `sizeof a` and `sizeof c` respectively, are more robust than using a magic number

Comment: You didn't state what size this `to the same value` is. For example, can it be a struct?

Comment: @Amber I literally just assumed `ints` were fixed size and segfaulted my morning away with `memset`

Answer (score 4):

`memset()` is used to set all the bytes in a block of memory to a particular char value. Memset also only plays well with `char` as it's its initialization value.

`memcpy()` copies bytes between memory. This type of data being copied is irrelevant, it just makes byte-for-byte copies.

Comment: I like this answer because of `to a particular char value`

Answer (score 3):

`memset` sets a block of memory to a single value. `memcpy` copies the content of a block into another block.

Perhaps you'd be interested in the difference between `memcpy` and `memmove`. Both do the same, but the latter works even if the source and destination overlap.

Comment: You didn't explicitly state  what size this `single value` is. I'm currently staring at `memset(buf, (int)(54 + n), 1);` as i wanted to find out wither the third parameter `1` will write the entire `int` into `buf` but it didn't instead it only write the least significant byte of the integer.

Comment: It is a single byte (char), as that is the type `memset` takes. Your number gets truncated in the function call.

Answer (score 1):

memset fill *memory* with constant byte

void *memset(void *s, int c, size_t n);

Use of memset is programmer can directly fill memory with particular.
and memcpy uses *constant* void pointer to source which cannot be changed.

memcpy copy the *memory* area

void *memcpy(void *dest, const void *src, size_t n);

Reference [memcpy](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memcpy.3.html)
          [memset](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memset.3.html)

Comment: Good, you describe the `with constant byte` in memset.

Comment: Thanks @truthadjustr I am happy that answer is helpful

Answer (score 0):

`memcpy()` copies from one place to another. `memset()` just sets all pieces of memory to the same.

For example here sets string length of the string str to * (or whatever second argument of the memset).

```
memset(str, '*', strlen(str)+1);
```

Here copies the string length  of the string src to dest.

`memcpy(dest, src, strlen(src)+1);`